# Is there any reason to use document.getElementById instead of the ID itself?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

For example, to remove an element from the DOM, `myEl.remove()` works just as well (in Firefox and Chrome) as `document.getElementById("myEl").remove()`

Comment: Some reasons discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-properties)

Comment: it is above all a question of readability and maintenance. For example you can name all your dom elements as x1, x2, x3,... x999999, while refraining from using any `getElementById`. But you risk hating yourself the day you have to debug your code. My advice: use meaningful names in the DOM part, such as  `unit-price` or `delivery-date` and abbreviated values of these elements in JS, but only in short and functional scope. developing good coding habits is essential.

Answer (score 1):

A couple, including name collisions with existing properties of `window` (which might change over time as new APIs are added):

```js
console.log(name === document.getElementById('name'));
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
```

and static analysis (is your undeclared variable a mistake, or do you expect it to be part of the document?) both by automated linters and human readers.